# insert into diff table using single HQL query in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, reflection

insert into diff  table using single HQL query in hibernate?
i think It can done using Reflection API. means dynamically call the method.

Comment: i do the select and delete using Reflection API..
i can't call the dynamically javabeans class method.
plz give me, what i do for call the dynamicall method of the class.

Comment: Not able to relate persistence, reflection & query together. Reading recommended http://www.hibernate.org/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling.

I got it using the reflection API.

You can get the Field name and the value from the Field name.

Then you can set the value to this POJO class and the call the default save method for insert data into database.

You got my point?